# If I open the form in a loop it won't show

Tags: c#, forms, loops

I try to recreate a situation where you press the button the second form which includes a video keeps showing every few seconds. If I leave the loop, the form shows up as it should but as soon as I loop it, I just get nothing just extra programs in my task bar but they wont show up.

My question is: if I am able to loop the program so when I click the button the form just keep popping up every few seconds and how i can achieve this.

Form 1 with button:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int loop = 0;
    while (loop < 10)
    {
        var myForm = new Form2();
        myForm.Show();
        Thread.Sleep(15000);
    }
}
```

the end result is to just repeat the form endlessly and that every time the form2 deploysand is visible.

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` makes the thread sleep, therefore not doing the UI work involved in rendering the form. Why are you using `Thread.Sleep`? Take that out and you'll get 10 forms that open up.

Comment: If you're wanting it to wait while the first form loads and runs, you can use `Task()` as to not block it's thread with `Thread.Sleep()`

Comment: if i take out sleep it spams my computer to death with forms. i need a delay before it opens another form

Comment: Use a `Timer` then instead of a while loop and have it tick off 10 times in 15 second intervals.

Comment: it spams because you never reach 10 as you never increment loop.